# How does garbage collector work in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, garbage-collection

I am learning about Kafka and came across garbage collector options in Kafka.

`MaxGCPauseMillis`, `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent`
(My question is not about these options.)

I want to know the basic **algorithm** (**logic**, or maybe **behavior**) of garbage collecting in Kafka.  It can be broad, but general idea of how it works in Kafka can give me a lot of insights. Any answers or information is appreciated, which will result in unconditional upvote and helping others like me.

Comment: garbage collecting is a JVM job. The used algorithm (default) is G1GC, but as said, it's not the broker's job, Kafka is just another process executing in a virtual machine

Comment: @aran hey thank you for your comment. Could you put this as an answer? looks useful. Maybe write more about G1GC for me in your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a section in the [official Kafka documentations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#java) that mention that LinkedIn is currently running JDK 1.8 and using G1GC.
They also shown their configuration:

```
-Xmx6g -Xms6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80
```

If you want to know more about tuning the G1GC for Kafka, I would recommend reading the [relevant section](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf#page=59) in the "***Kafka: The Definitive Guide***" book, where they talk about the two parameters that you mentioned - `MaxGCPauseMillis` and `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent`.

Don't forget to read the [JVM Monitoring chapter](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf#page=254) as well, you can learn a lot by monitoring your JVM.